# Show density and frequency on the same histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I would like to see both the density and frequency on my histogram. For example, display density on the left side and frequency on the right side.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [6.950915827194559, 0.5704464713012669, -1.655326152372283, 5.867122206816244, -1.809359944941513, -6.164821482653027, -2.538999462076397, 0.2108693568484643, -8.740600769897465, 2.121232876712331, 7.967032967032961, 10.61701196601832, 1.847419201771516, 0.6858006670780847, -2.008695652173909, 2.86991153132885, 1.703131050506168, -1.346913193356314, 3.334927671049193, -15.64688995215311, 20.00022688856367, 10.05956454173731, 2.044936877124148, 3.06513409961684, -0.9973614775725559, 1.190631873030967, -1.509991311902692, -0.3333827233664155, 1.898473282442747, 1.618299899267539, -0.1897860593512823, 1.000000000000001, 3.03501945525293, -7.646697418593529, -0.9769069279216391, -2.918403811792736, -3.90929422276739, 9.609846259653532, 3.240690674452962, 10.08973134408675, 1.98356309650054, 1.915301127899549, -0.7792207792207684, -3.308682400714091, -3.312977099236647, 19.98101265822785, 3.661973444534827, -5.770676691729326, 0.5268044012063156, -1.573767040370533, 3.234974862888484, -1.514352732634994, 6.564849624060143, 9.956794019127146, 3.232590278195024, 2.042007001166857, 1.601164483260553, -2.384737678855331, -2.731242556570068, 0.6069707315088602, 1.40561881957264, -6.805306861851957, 2.492102492102499, -3.639688275501762, 0.7958485384154335, 2.799187725631769, 0.9195966872689088, -2.366608280379856, 0.797679477882518, -3.80380434782609]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["Returns"])

def plot_histogram():
    
    bins = range(-11, 12, 1)
    bins_str = []
    for i in bins:
        bins_str.append(str(i)+"%")
        
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
    _, bins, patches = plt.hist(np.clip(df.Returns, bins[0], bins[-1]), 
                                bins=bins, density=True, rwidth=0.8)
    
    xlabels = bins_str[:]
    xlabels[-1] = "Over"
    xlabels[0] = "Under"
    
    N_labels = len(xlabels)
    plt.xlim([bins[0], bins[-1]])
    plt.xticks(bins)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
    plt.title("Returns distribution")
    plt.grid(axis="y", linewidth=0.5)

    
plot_histogram()
```

I tried adding `density=True` in `plt.hist()` but it removes the count from the histogram. Is it possible to display both the frequency and density on the same histogram?

Comment: You can just add a second axis with `twiny` making sure you compute the scale correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A density plot sets the heights of the bars such that the area of all the bars (taking `rwidth=1` for that calculation) sums to 1.  As such, the bar heights of a counting histogram get divided by (the number of values times the bar widths).

With that conversion factor, you can recalculate the counts from the density (or vice versa).  The recalculation can be used to label the bars and/or set a secondary y-axis.  Note that the ticks of both y axes are aligned, so the grid only works well for one of them. (A secondary y-axis is a bit different from `ax.twiny()`, as the former has a fixed conversion between both y axes).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [6.950915827194559, 0.5704464713012669, -1.655326152372283, 5.867122206816244, -1.809359944941513, -6.164821482653027, -2.538999462076397, 0.2108693568484643, -8.740600769897465, 2.121232876712331, 7.967032967032961, 10.61701196601832, 1.847419201771516, 0.6858006670780847, -2.008695652173909, 2.86991153132885, 1.703131050506168, -1.346913193356314, 3.334927671049193, -15.64688995215311, 20.00022688856367, 10.05956454173731, 2.044936877124148, 3.06513409961684, -0.9973614775725559, 1.190631873030967, -1.509991311902692, -0.3333827233664155, 1.898473282442747, 1.618299899267539, -0.1897860593512823, 1.000000000000001, 3.03501945525293, -7.646697418593529, -0.9769069279216391, -2.918403811792736, -3.90929422276739, 9.609846259653532, 3.240690674452962, 10.08973134408675, 1.98356309650054, 1.915301127899549, -0.7792207792207684, -3.308682400714091, -3.312977099236647, 19.98101265822785, 3.661973444534827, -5.770676691729326, 0.5268044012063156, -1.573767040370533, 3.234974862888484, -1.514352732634994, 6.564849624060143, 9.956794019127146, 3.232590278195024, 2.042007001166857, 1.601164483260553, -2.384737678855331, -2.731242556570068, 0.6069707315088602, 1.40561881957264, -6.805306861851957, 2.492102492102499, -3.639688275501762, 0.7958485384154335, 2.799187725631769, 0.9195966872689088, -2.366608280379856, 0.797679477882518, -3.80380434782609]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["Returns"])

bins = range(-11, 12, 1)
bins_str = [str(i) + "%" for i in bins]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
values, bins, patches = ax.hist(np.clip(df["Returns"], bins[0], bins[-1]),
                                bins=bins, density=True, rwidth=0.8)
# conversion between counts and density: number of values times bin width
factor = len(df) * (bins[1] - bins[0])

ax.bar_label(patches, ['' if v == 0 else f'{v * factor:.0f}' for v in values])
xlabels = bins_str[:]
xlabels[-1] = "Over"
xlabels[0] = "Under"

ax.set_xlim([bins[0], bins[-1]])
ax.set_xticks(bins, xlabels)
ax.set_title("Returns distribution")
ax.grid(axis="y", linewidth=0.5)

secax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(lambda y: y * factor, lambda y: y / factor))
secax.set_ylabel('counts')
ax.set_ylabel('density')

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib histogram with density and counts]

To have the same grid positions for both y-axes, you can copy the ticks of one and convert them to set them at the other.  For the ticks to be calculated, the plot needs to be drawn once (at the end of the code). Note that the converted values are only shown with a limited number of digits.

```py
fig.canvas.draw()
ax.set_yticks(secax.get_yticks() / factor)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with two y axes with aligned grid]